# Filter product collection which only has image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, product-collection

i try to filter product collection to get a product collection which only has at least one image like this:

```
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('image', array("neq"=>'no_selection'));
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array("neq"=>'no_selection'));
```

but it's not working at all, it still shows the product with the placeholder image

Comment: Did you get solution for your problem by any of below answers? If you are facing any issue with any of the answer, you can add comment for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other idea ... get all unique `entity_id` *(product Ids)* from `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table and use result to filter collection.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read     = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query    = $read->select()
    ->from($resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery'), array('entity_id'))
    ->distinct(true)
    ->group('entity_id');
$result = $read->query($query);

$productIds = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $productIds[] = $row['entity_id'];
}
```

For your collection

```
$collection->addIdFilter($productIds);
```

---

**Edit:**

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('small_image, thumbnail, image');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'image','neq' => 'no_selection'),
        array('attribute' => 'small_image','neq' => 'no_selection'),
        array('attribute' => 'thumbnail','neq' => 'no_selection'),
    )
);
```

***Note:*** for performance I'd use first approach.